# How can i find the pixel color range in an image that excludes outliers?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, pixel

I have this code that randomly generates 10 pixel locations with in the image dimensions. I then want to take each pixel location and find the GBR value and then find the largest g value, b value, r value and the smallest g value b value and r value. I then found some code that can take those color boundaries and create a mask image. I might want to incorporate  a mean g, b , r value and compute the standard deviation for each and use that to eliminate the outliers.

or instead of using the code i wrote to generate 10 random pixels if there a way to get the color range inside of +- 1 standard deviation of the mean color of the image?

see code below:

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np
import random

name = "Highway"

img = cv2.imread(name + ".jpg")
inc = 10
n = 10
rpixel=[]

# grabs bottom center of image, keeps image ratio. the larger the inc is the smaller the imaged grabed

def bottomcenter(inc,img):

    y,x,z = img.shape
    h = x/2
    x1 = h - (x/inc)
    x2 = h + (x/inc)
    y1 = y - (y/inc)
    y2 = y 

    bcsample = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    return(bcsample)


# generates a random selection of pixels

def randompixel(img,n):

    y,x,z = img.shape

    for i in range (n):
        xrand = random.randrange(0,x)
        yrand = random.randrange(0,y)
        rpix = yrand,xrand
        rpixel.append(rpix)
    return(rpixel)



roadsample = bottomcenter(inc,img)

randompixel(roadsample,n)




for i in rpixel:

    #px=B.G.R   
    px = roadsample[i]

    for b,g,r in px: 
        ub = max(b)
        ug = max(g)
        ur = max(r)
        lb = min(b)
        lg = min(g)
        lr = min(r)

boundary = [([lb,lg,lr],[ub,ug,ur])]

print(boundary)

#for (lower, upper) in boundary:
    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
#   lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
#   upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")

# find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
# the mask
#mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
#output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)

# save the images
#cv2.imwrite(name + "_roadarea.png", np.hstack([img, output]))
```

Comment: I also am getting this error

Comment: I also am getting this error.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\roadfinder.py", line 55, in <module>
    for b,g,r in px:
TypeError: 'numpy.uint8' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code :

Firstly, you should change

```
randompixel(roadsample,n)
```

to

```
rpixel=randompixel(roadsample,n)
```

even though it works because Python is nice and rpixel is delcared beforehand, it's messy : your randompixel function is returning rpixel and you are forgetting about it.

Secondly,the error you mention in a comment comes from your double for loop. The first for loop is OK, it will loop for every item in rpixel. The following line

```
px = roadsample[i]
```

gets the corresponding pixel in the cropped image, ok. So px is a 3 element array. To iterate in it you need to do something like

```
for color in px
```

not

```
for b,g,r in px
```

Because here you are trying to iterate on all elements of px at once. That is what your error is telling you, "I can't iterate over the b value of px, because it's only a number !"
It seems you're new to programming, don't hesitate to use a lot of "print" or a debug IDE to see what your variables look like at any given time

Finally, for your question, if I understood correctly, here is a proposed code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def bottomcenter(inc,img):
    y,x,z = img.shape
    h = x/2
    x1 = h - (x/inc)
    x2 = h + (x/inc)
    y1 = y - (y/inc)
    y2 = y 
    bcsample = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    return(bcsample)

#read image
full_road = cv2.imread(fullroad_path)

#crop road to get a part of road where there is no line
inc=10
cropped_road=bottomcenter(inc,road)

#seperate image in each channel (yes, you can do that, numpy is handy !)
blue=cropped_road[:,:,0]; green=cropped_road[:,:,1]; red=cropped_road[:,:,2];

#computing mean and std of each channel
blue_mean=np.mean(blue); green_mean=np.mean(green); red_mean=np.mean(red);
blue_std=np.std(blue); green_std=np.std(green); red_std=np.std(red);

#getting positions of pixels in [color +-std]
mask = cv2.inRange(fullroad, np.array([blue_mean-blue_std,green_mean-green_std,red_mean-red_std]), np.array([blue_mean+blue_std,green_mean+green_std,red_mean+red_std]))
#masking the image
output = cv2.bitwise_and(full_road, full_road, mask = mask)
```

Comment: First, thank you for your quick and thorough response. yes I am new. just started with python a week ago. don't really have much experience otherwise.

Comment: First, thank you for your quick and thorough response. yes I am new. just started with python a week ago. don't really have much experience otherwise. 
as you see in the code. I take an image and crop it to get the bottom center of the image, the image is of a road. as you know a road has varying colors on it. especially when different lights are hitting it. my goal is to find the entire road and outline it. so I figured if I could get a sample of the various road colors, it could help me find the whole road. but if it picks up a white or yellow line it could throw everything off.

Comment: so if I could find the pixel color range of the road and eliminate instances where it might pick up the dashed white line or the solid line on the road that would be ideal

Comment: so is your variable "roadsample"  your road image cropped specifically in order to have a part of the road where there will be no "white or yellow line" ?

Comment: yes, with this image it will not pick up the line. but I am trying to make it work with any image. as if the camera is mounted on the car so the center bottom would always be road.

Comment: OK, I'm still not 100%sure I understood everything (the random pixel part is throwing me a little off), but I edited my answer, can you take a look ?

Comment: that worked really well! just what I was looking for. do you have any suggestions for pictures where it might pick up the white or yellow line?

maybe if its possible to take the mean and 1 stdv like you have for each color then remove everything outside of the 1 stdv and then calculate the mean and stdv again. I would think that the white and yellow lines would be outside the 1 stdv from the mean so that would be eliminated then when you recalc again for the mean and stdv it should have a mean that's closer to the median. maybe?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a bas idea.
I can't really give you guidelines as everything depends on your type of image, how different they are from one another... Maybe you don't need to handle the white and yellow lines differently, if you manage to detect the black of the road, then you can post process it by closing (see morphological operations) or taking the biggest edges (if by "finding the road" you mean edge detection) (see connected components). If your road is straight, you might wanna look at Hough Transforms.
It depends on what you have, want, and can do ;) Good luck !

Comment: Thanks!, I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Solitius, how would you handle this?

# this part of the code.
blue=cropped_road[:,:,0]; green=cropped_road[:,:,1]; red=cropped_road[:,:,2];
#how would you take the blue=cropped_road[:,:,0] and add another blue=cropped_road[:,:,0]; from another cropped part of the main picture.

I want it to remain a list so that I can append multiple times and then take the mean of the entire appended blue array.
blue.append(blue)